# How to achieve Offline chat(Wifi chat) concept in android 2.2 and above?

Tags: android, chat, offline-mode

I'm new to android. I would like to achieve the "Offline Chat" concept in android(2.2 and above). I know this is possible in android 4.0(and above) because the WifiDirect (Wifi P2P) function is available. But how can I achieve this in android 2.2 without using Wifi Direct?
Is it possible to chat in Tethering network?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is only about the connectivity between the two devices, I'd think that you should be able to use Bluetooth for that. You'll find information about how to use Bluetooth here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Most of the API's used there have been added in API Level 5, which corresponds to Android 2.0 (Eclair) and should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Thanks Chnoch. We can achieve this by bluetooth concept. But i want larger coverage(Using Wifi) that will discover more devices than bluetooth.

Comment: If you have an external Wifi AccessPoint then of course it won't be that hard. But since WifiDirect has only been implemented in Android 4.0 I believe you're out of luck otherwise.

Comment: yes Chnoch. But i heard 'Wifi tethering' concept will solve this problem(Like SuperBeam Andorid App Works). But i dont know whether this solution is suitable for my question. Do you have any idea about 'Wifi tethering'?